# Styled Media Receiver and DRM

Tags: chromecast, drm

I was told my word of mouth that it is possible to do DRM with the Styled Media Receiver by sending credentials through the manifest? Sorry if this is vague but this is something I heard from someone briefly. I want to know is it possible to set DRM credentials if using Styled Media Receiver? How does DRM work with styled media receiver? Any information on DRM and Styled Media Receiver would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Styled Media Receiver supports DRM if the licence URL is embedded in the media manifest.

Comment: I am trying try to cast a HLS stream. Is there a certain parameter or certain api that I need to include in the manifest?

Comment: You should read up how HLS supports DRM: http://docs.unified-streaming.com/documentation/protect/hls-with-aes.html

Comment: I am having an issue. how my drm works is its all handled by a library. The drm provider gets the material from the cdn and sends my android device a drm hls stream. I do not have access to license url. Any support for this kind of drm?

Comment: For custom DRM handling you need to create a custom receiver.

Comment: Yes I understand. I also have a custom receiver but how do I handle the DRM without using the license url? Like I said before I only get the drm encoded stream.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the license URL from the streaming server (in the manifest file), so the receiver can send a request to the license server. Take a look at this example from Google which shows how to play DRM content: https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM

Comment: Got it. Do you know where I can find a HLS stream and a license URL for testing?

Comment: No, sorry. I have some URLs for HLS treams, but not with DRM. In our project, we're using smooth streaming with DRM